# I Want To Apply Delay On Mouse Out in css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to apply a delay before starting a CSS transition on mouse out event. My CSS code is below, please let me know how to apply time delay before CSS transition on mouse out starts.

I want to achieve that the menu stays stable for some time (e.g. for 3 seconds) after the user moves mouse pointer out of the menu.

```
.timnav li .dropdown {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 230px;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }

.timnav li:hover .dropdown {
    min-height: 60px;
    max-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
            -webkit-transition: delay .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: delay .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: delay .5s ease-in-out;
}

.timnav li .dropdown ul {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top:7px;


}

.timnav li .dropdown ul > li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: none;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}


    .timnav li .dropdown  .dropdown2{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: none; 
}

    .timnav li .dropdown ul > li:hover .dropdown2{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: none;

}

    .timnav li .dropdown .dropdown2:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: none;


}


    .timnav li .dropdown .dropdown2 li a {
    display: block;
    padding-left:7px !important;
    height:6 !important;
    padding-top:8px;
    background: url(../images/nav-bg.jpg) repeat; color:#fff;

}


.timnav li .dropdown ul > li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: url(../images/nav-crrent.jpg) repeat; color:#FFFFFF;

}

.timnav ul .dropdown ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.timnav li .dropdown li a:hover {
    background: url(../images/nav-bg.jpg) repeat; color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add a delay to a transition, the syntax is as follows:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 3s;
```

So

```
transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
```

The syntax is the same for all the prefixed versions also.

I have created a demo of this, because you need to do something a bit tricky in order to make the item appear with no delay, but delay before it goes.

http://jsfiddle.net/pgqM2/

The trick is to re-define the transition to add the 3s delay when there is no hover, but to have a 0s delay when there is a hover:

```
li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 3s;
}

li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working, can you tell me where should i embed webkit delay, Please check me css cods. is you want live link then i'll post here.

Comment: I have added a link to a simple JSFiddle demo. The syntax is the same for all of the prefixes, whether it is `-o` or `-webkit` etc.

Comment: Thanks Steve Fenton,

it's working but not appending on whole, the dropdown hide quickly.
and on chrome on mouse out dropdown cut in to peice. not showing whole.
i'll send you website URL if you can help me.

Answer (score 6):

There is a `transition-delay` property in CSS. Simply add this to your code, and you will get the desired effect.

```
transition-delay:3s;
```

For the purpose of shorthand transition properties, here is a picture that sums it up

[image: transition: <property> || <duration> || <timing-function> || <delay> [, ...];]

So in your case it would look like this

```css
div:hover {
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out 3s;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out 3s;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out 3s;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out 3s;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me. There is a delay!</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43nGr/1) to demonstrate

Comment: Thanks but its not working, can you tell me where should i embed webkit delay, Please check me css cods. is you want live link then i'll post here.

Comment: Please make sure to use the unprefixed version, too (which also adds IE support). (And note that Chrome 26, Firefox 16, and Opera 12.1 all unprefixed `transition`, so at least `-moz-` may not be necessary for much longer if at all.)

Answer (score 3):

You cant use css transition when using display none, only solution with display none is js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css3 property [transition-delay](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp) to delay executing css. Click "Try it Yourself" to see an example.

Comment: Thanks but its not working, can you tell me where should i embed webkit delay, Please check me css cods. is you want live link then i'll post here.