# Hover Fade-Out Blues

Tags: css, transition

After looking around online to no avail, I found this stackoverflow posting:

[I Want To Apply Delay On Mouse Out in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203240/i-want-to-apply-delay-on-mouse-out-in-css)

that looked like it would work in order to let a dropdown remain for a few seconds before disappearing. I looked at the 'fiddle' linked to and the CSS seemed simple enough. But for some reason it's not working on my code. Here is the code and I'm hoping someone can point out what may be preventing the fiddle solution from working. Thank You

Daniel

```css
#nav{z-index:200;position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:100%;color:#fff}
#nav ul{padding:0;margin:0;list-style:none}
#nav ul ul{display:block!important}
#nav ul:before,#nav ul:after{content:"";display:table}
#nav ul:after{clear:both}
#nav li{display:block}
#nav li a{display:block;color:#B0B0B0;font-size:.875em;line-height:1.28571em;font-weight:700;outline:none}
#nav li a:focus,#nav li a:hover{color:blue;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1)}
#nav li.is-active a{color:red}
#nav li ul{position:absolute;width:auto;left:-999em}
#nav li:hover ul{left:auto;display:block;background:#F2F2F2;font-family:'Times New Roman',serif}
nav ul li:hover ul{display:block;width:400px;padding:5px;height:auto}
```

Comment: You need to post your markup so we have a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.

Here's a link to the test page on the server. In the first paragraph I explain what I'm attempting. Note: menu in question is only for above 768px.  http://sitesetis.com/navtest1/navtest.html